# Why was Worf raised by humans when he had cousins on Qo'noS?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, worf

On [Worf's page](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Worf) on memory alpha, it said that Worf was allowed to be raised by humans *"After the Klingon Empire stated that the young boy apparently had no living relatives"*. Then it was said that *"Worf voyaged to Qo'noS, where he stayed with cousins of the House of Mogh in 2355"*. Isn't this contradictory?
Plus, why would not they allow another Klingon family to adopt him to raise him in their honorable ways?  Especially that at the time Mogh, Worf's father was honorable and was not yet accused of treason until 2366.

Comment: He even had a brother on Qo'noS.

Comment: But the identity of his brother was hidden for so many years.

Comment: "Cousin" can mean anything from "first cousin" to "vaguely-related kin". It could just be that the relatives on Qo'noS weren't close enough to be considered family for some purposes.

Answer (score 7):

Remember that at the time the Klingon Empire said Worf had no living relatives the house of Duras was in the middle of a purge of the house of Mogh after framing them for assisting the Romulans in the attack on Khitomer.  Officially he may not have had any known living relatives, all having been executed as traitors or in hiding as Kurn was.  In fact, the official who gave that report to the Federation probably saved Worf life.  With his family declared traitors if Worf had been returned to the empire he would have been executed for treason.